# How can I get `sns.kdeplot` and a manually-generated KDE to match?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, kernel-density

I have been generating filled KDEs using `sns.kdeplot`. To try to better understand what's going on under the hood, I decided to try estimating the KDE myself and plotting the kde using `plt.contourf`, using code I found in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917216/log-scales-with-seaborn-kdeplot). However, my results using the two methods look quite different. I've tried to make sure my implementation of the KDE estimation matches the way it's done in Seaborn, and I can't find any discrepancies. Can someone help me understand why my plots do not look the same?

Here is some example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

geyser = sns.load_dataset("geyser")

dur = np.array(geyser["duration"])
wait = np.array(geyser["waiting"])

# plot the KDE using sns.kdeplot
sns.kdeplot(dur, wait, shade=True, cmap="binary", cut=0)

# calculate my own KDE and plot using plt.contourf
def make_kde(x, y):
    """
    Based on
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917216/log-scales-with-seaborn-kdeplot
    """
    kde = stats.gaussian_kde([x, y])
    
    xx, yy = np.mgrid[min(x):max(x):(max(x)-min(x))/200,
                      min(y):max(y):(max(y)-min(y))/200]
    
    
    
    density = kde(np.c_[xx.flat, yy.flat].T).reshape(xx.shape)
    
    return xx, yy, density

xgrid, ygrid, density = make_kde(dur, wait)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.contourf(xgrid, ygrid, density, cmap="binary", levels=10)
```

Here is the plot generated by `sns.kdeplot`:

[image]

And here is the plot generated by `plt.contourf`:

[image]

I would really appreciate any tips for trying to understand why these two plots look different.